# Leadsource not mapped to accountsource upon conversion

Tags: lead-conversion

When we convert a lead, it's LeadSource is NOT been shown in the AccountSource.

The one error I see, is that in the `Lead Custom Field Mapping`  The field is not mapped

[image]

But I don't have the field: AccountSource in the drop down list (it's not a custom field)

- I can see that both the field: LeadSource and AccountSource are actually the same list.

But when I create a lead, and covert it - the AccountSource is empty

[image]

Answer (score 2):

http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=lead_conversion_mapping.htm

Have a look at the document above and as per this

> **Lead source is mapped to contact and opportunity lead source .so workaround will be to have custom field created**

1. Go developer route and create trigger that will react on conversion and bring appropriate value to Account custom field.
2. Create another custom field on Lead object and using workflow rule copy value of Lead Source in it. After that map this new Lead custom field with Account custom field for pasing values in conversion moment. (No development involved).